# How to get the second column from command output?

Tags: shell, awk, ksh

My command's output is something like:

```
1540 "A B"
   6 "C"
 119 "D"
```

The first column is always a number, followed by a space, then a double-quoted string.

My purpose is to get the second column only, like:

```
"A B"
"C"
"D"
```

I intended to use `<some_command> | awk '{print $2}'` to accomplish this. But the question is, some values in the second column contain space(s), which happens to be the default delimiter for `awk` to separate the fields. Therefore, the output is messed up:

```
"A
"C"
"D"
```

How do I get the second column's value (with paired quotes) cleanly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961635/using-awk-to-print-all-columns-from-the-nth-to-the-last

Comment: I tried using `awk '{$1=""; print $0}'`, but it still has a leading white space character. It could be removed by `sed '/^ //'`. Yet, could this be done with `awk`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Or use sed & regex.

```
<some_command> | sed 's/^.* \(".*"$\)/\1/'
```

Comment: Shorter cmd as you do not need start and end markers: `<some_command> | sed 's/.* \(".*"\)/\1/'`

Comment: It would be nice if anyone could explain a little bit on what `'s/^.* \(".*"$\)/\1/'` stands for

Comment: `^` marks the beginning of the line

`.*` means any sequence of characters

`\(` and `\)` marks a « captured » group of character, what we will treat as \1 in the Right hand side of the sed sequence

".*" means any sequence of chars between quotes

$ marks the end of the line

Answer (score 311):

Use `-F [field separator]` to split the lines on `"`s:

```
awk -F '"' '{print $2}' your_input_file
```

or for input from pipe

```
<some_command> | awk -F '"' '{print $2}'
```

output:

```
A B
C
D
```

Comment: This is good, but I also want the original surrounding quotes. Could it be done? Thanks.

Comment: you could cheat, and change awk's print to `'{print "\""$2"\""}'`

Comment: Yup, this works. Thanks a lot, Alex! By the way, so many quotes, :)

Comment: @Alex, could you explain how you used the double quotation marks and backslash to get what the op wanted.

Comment: @Timo The quotes and backslashes breakdown can be envisioned as `"\"" + $2 + "\""`.  The surrounding quotation marks are indicating something to be appended to the output, and the escaped quotation mark (`\"`) is being printed.  To help visualize it, this is what it would look like if we wanted to add blank spaces around `$2` instead of quotation marks: `'{print " "$2" "}'`.  We can also add format spacing to make it a little easier to grok: `'{print " " $2 " "}'`

Answer (score 122):

If you could use something other than 'awk' , then try this instead

```
echo '1540 "A B"' | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

**-d** is a delimiter, **-f** is the field to cut and with **-f2-**  we intend to cut the 2nd field until end.

Comment: this helped me trying to do following (fetch commit id of a file in git):
git annotate myfile.cpp | grep '2016-07' | head -1| cut -f1

Comment: This is good, but does not work if delimiter is more than one character long. That's where the awk solution comes in handy

Comment: Why is a space not used after `-d`? It looks a bit odd in that way.

Comment: if your output has more than one column and you only need the second column, use ```cut -d' ' -f2```

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski: You can also do: ` cut -d\  -f2-`  (note: two spaces after the back-slash!)  Does that look less odd ?

Answer (score 105):

This should work to get a specific column out of the command output "docker images":

```
REPOSITORY                          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
ubuntu                              16.04               12543ced0f6f        10 months ago       122 MB
ubuntu                              latest              12543ced0f6f        10 months ago       122 MB
selenium/standalone-firefox-debug   2.53.0              9f3bab6e046f        12 months ago       613 MB
selenium/node-firefox-debug         2.53.0              d82f2ab74db7        12 months ago       613 MB


docker images | awk '{print $3}'

IMAGE
12543ced0f6f
12543ced0f6f
9f3bab6e046f
d82f2ab74db7
```

This is going to print the third column

Comment: Have you seen out put of docker images | awk '{print $5}'  ?

Comment: @ShashiRanjan No, what was it?

Comment: This seems to break on any row with an empty value.

Comment: This breaks as "IMAGE ID" has a space in between.

Comment: Why does this work despite not specifiying the field separator?

Answer (score 23):

You don't need awk for that. Using `read` in Bash shell should be enough, e.g.

```
some_command | while read c1 c2; do echo $c2; done
```

or:

```
while read c1 c2; do echo $c2; done < in.txt
```

Comment: You should always use the `-r` argument with read, especially when you don't know what the input will be. Otherwise backslashes will mess things up.

Comment: If using this beware that if the "read" column count is less than the input columns then the last variable will contain all the remaining fields (ie. the last variable might not contain only that column).

Answer (score 13):

If you have GNU awk this is the solution you want:

```
$ awk '{print $1}' FPAT='"[^"]+"' file
"A B"
"C"
"D"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F"|" '{gsub(/\"/,"|");print "\""$2"\""}' your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys 

col = int(sys.argv[1]) - 1

for line in sys.stdin:
    columns = line.split()

    try:
        print(columns[col])
    except IndexError:
        # ignore
        pass
```

Then, supposing you name the script as co, say, do something like this to get the sizes of files (the example assumes you're using Linux, but the script itself is OS-independent) :-

`ls -lh | co 5`