# Extracting columns from multiple files into a single output file from the command line

Tags: linux, command-line, awk

Say I have a tab-delimited data file with 10 columns. With awk, it's easy to extract column 7, for example, and output that into a separate file. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136943), for example.)

What if I have 5 such data files, and I would like to extract column 7 from each of them and make a new file with 5 data columns, one for the column 7 of each input file? Can this be done from the command line with awk and other commands?

Or should I just write up a Python script to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk '{a[FNR] = a[FNR]" " $7}END{for(i=0;i<FNR;i++) print a[i]}'`

`a` array holds each line from different files

`FNR` number of records read in current input file, set to zero at begining of each file.

`END{for(i=0;i<FNR;i++) print a[i]}` prints the content of array `a` on `END` of file

Answer (score 0):

If the data is small enough to store it all in memory then this should work:

```
awk '{out[FNR]=out[FNR] (out[FNR]?OFS:"") $7; max=(FNR>max)?FNR:max} END {for (i=1; i<=max; i++) {print out[i]}}' file1 file2 file3 file4 file5
```

If it isn't then you would need something fancier which could seek around file streams or read single lines from multiple files (a shell loop with N calls to `read` could do this).