# get multiple columns from multiple files into a single file shell

Tags: bash, shell, multiple-columns

Hi,
      I have multiple files with the multiple columns, I want to select few different columns from every file and make it to single file. I have read the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26342838/extracting-columns-from-multiple-files-into-a-single-output-file-from-the-comman)

file1

```
Day   present absent total
Mon    10      1      11 
TUE    11      0      11
WED     9      2      11
THU     8      3      11 
...
```

file2

```
Day   present absent total
Mon    18      3      21 
TUE    15      6      21
WED    19      2      21
THU    17      4      21 
....
```

file 3

```
Day   present absent total
Mon    50      1      51 
TUE    51      0      51
WED    49      2      51
THU    48      3      51 
....
```

make it to single file

```
Day   present present present
Mon    10      18      50 
TUE    11      15      51
WED     9      19      49
THU     8      17      48
 ....
```

How can I make it with shell/bash command?

```
[awk '{a\[FNR\] = a\[FNR\]" " $7}END{for(i=0;i<FNR;i++) print a\[i\]}'][2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quick way to do it:

```
 paste file1 file2 file3|awk '{print $1, $2, $6, $10}'
```

if you want the output to be in a "pretty" format, `paste 1 2 3|awk -v OFS='\t' '{print...}'` or pipe the output to `|column -t`.

output:

```
Day  present  present  present
Mon  10       18       50
TUE  11       15       51
WED  9        19       49
THU  8        17       48
```

Comment: It did n't worked for single file having around 80 columns bcause it conatin zero valus in  most of cells ... I sticked to the previous answer   ' awk '{a\[FNR\] = a\[FNR\]" " $7}END{for(i=0;i<FNR;i++) print a\[i\]}' '  and then created a single file using paste command ...