# For Regex, if the two pattern are all greedy, how does the pattern engine chose the match practically?

Tags: regex, regex-greedy, regex-group

Yesterday , I and my roommate discussed a question on the stack. And this questions is here

**[How to get the second column from command output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136943/how-to-get-the-second-column-from-command-output-with-awk)**

They talk about how to separate the second column from the input stream like this:

```
1540 "A B"
   6 "C"
 119 "D"
```

And with the first upvoted answer

```
<some_command> | sed 's/^.* \(".*"$\)/\1/'
```

the result is perfectly satisfied with the request.

But then we find if we follow the greedy rule of regex, the pattern `^.*␣` will match `1540 "A` which confused my roommate. With the benefit of hindsight, the pattern `^.*␣` should make a compromise with the pattern `(".*"$)`. Otherwise, the second pattern would match nothing. However, my roommate can't be convinced by my hypothesis. So this guy give me another example to test and we did do it.

We made two experiment. The **1st** add a quote `"` follow the character A like this:

```
1540 "A" B"
   6 "C"
 119 "D"
```

and it is easy to get this result with the previous regex code:

```
"A" B"
"C"
"D"
```

And for the **2nd** one , we add a white space and a quote `␣"` follow the A like this:

```
1540 "A " B"
   6 "C"
 119 "D"
```

the result is:

```
" B"
"C"
"D"
```

Until now, my roommate got more confused, cause his focus always concentrate on the second pattern `(".*"$)`. And in his mind, the pattern `(".*"$)` should observer the same behavior between the two string `1540 "A" B"` and `1540 "A " B"` , so the second test's result should be `"A " B"` not rather `" B"`. And I think for the second one , it's sure that the pattern `^.*␣` can't match this part `1540 "A"` which will result in no match for the second pattern. But for the second experiment `1540 "A " B"` , the two choice `"1540` and `1540 "A` seem all reasonable , the difference is that the former results from the greed of `(".*"$)` , the latter thanks to `^.*␣`'s.

So can anyone give me an answer more specifically to discern which is the key in our confusion.  Thanks .

Comment: I think some sort of undefined behavior here...

Comment: @vp_arth undefined behavoir? Sorry I don't understand.  In my opinion, the logic should be fixed even thought semantic is ambiguous for humans. Shouldn't the code always choose the same behavior?

Comment: I just believe, it's implementation dependent... I can be false here. Second `.*` can't be more greedy than first one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `.*` pattern is **greedy** in the sense that it will first attempt to match as much as it can, and then backtrack through the string, matching less and less, when necessary. Regular expressions are matched left-to-right, which means the first `.*`'s greediness will dominate the second's in the case of ambiguity.

### Let's apply this idea to `1540 "A" B"`.

Simplified, the regex is:

```
^.* (".*")$
```

- First, try to match the *whole* string with the first `.*`.

  - Drat, we need to match a space next!
- OK, Let's try *everything* until the last space: `1540 "A"`.

  - No good. A quote `"` must follow the space.
- Well, let's look backwards a bit further... Here, the space after `1540` is followed by a quote.

Then, it will match the rest of the expression and succeed. So the **greediest match** for the first `.*` is `1540`, and the group matches the rest of the string, `"A" B"`.

### Now let's apply it to `1540 "A " B"`.

- First, try to match the *whole* string with the first `.*`.

  - Drat, we need to match a space next!
- OK, Let's try *everything* until the last space: `1540 "A "`.

  - No good. A quote `"` must follow the space.
- Well, let's look backwards a bit further... Oh, look! The space after `1540 "A` is followed by a quote! We can be slightly greedier than last time.

The **greediest match** for the first `.*` is now `1540 "A`, and the group will match the rest of the string, `" B"`.

Comment: thanks, I think that I forget to think about the quote `"` following the space, so in fact the regex would work together and then use the parentheses to capture the second matching pattern?