# get string from lines of file in bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, grep, cut

I have these lines in file :

```
postgres  2609 21030  0 12:49 ?        00:00:00 postgres: postgres postgres [local] idle in transaction                                                                     
postgres  2758 21030  0 12:51 ?        00:00:00 postgres: postgres postgres [local] idle in transaction                                                                     
postgres 28811 21030  0 09:26 ?        00:00:00 postgres: postgres postgres [local] idle in transaction                                                                     
postgres 32200 21030  0 11:40 ?        00:00:00 postgres: postgres postgres [local] idle in transaction                                                                     
postgres 32252 21030  0 11:41 ?        00:00:00 postgres: postgres postgres [local] idle in transaction
```

I need to separate second column values to process them.I have done this code :

```
pid=$(cat idle_log.txt | cut -d" " -f2)
echo $pid
```

but it only gave me 28811 32200 32252 in results.as you see there is no trace of 2609 2758 in list,I want to get them too.
Also I want count them after extracting pids.
I used :

```
npid=$(grep -o " " <<< $pid | grep -c .)
```

it returns 2 for results of 28811 32200 32252 I need it return 3 as count of processes.
finally I want to process some thing line by line like in a loop with while but output of commands return results at once,and I can't process them in loop format and one by one.

thank you all for help.

Comment: See: [How to get the second column from command output?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16136943/3776858)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat data 
postgres  2609 21030  0 12:49 ?        00:00:00 postgres: postgres postgres [local] idle in transaction
postgres  2758 21030  0 12:51 ?        00:00:00 postgres: postgres postgres [local] idle in transaction
postgres 28811 21030  0 09:26 ?        00:00:00 postgres: postgres postgres [local] idle in transaction
postgres 32200 21030  0 11:40 ?        00:00:00 postgres: postgres postgres [local] idle in transaction
postgres 32252 21030  0 11:41 ?        00:00:00 postgres: postgres postgres [local] idle in transaction   I need to extract second column from each line, 
$ awk '{print $2}' data 
2609
2758
28811
32200
32252
```

or you can squeeze multiple spaces into 1 using `tr` and then use `cut` like this:

```
$ tr -s ' ' < data | cut -d ' ' -f 2
2609
2758
28811
32200
32252
```

Edit:

```
$ tr -s ' ' < data | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | while read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
> echo "$line" #put your custom processing logic here
> done
2609
2758
28811
32200
32252
```

Comment: Thanks,have you any idea to not output them at once ? I need to read values line by line . . .

Comment: I want to calculate elapsed time of Idle in transaction processes and if they passed five minutes I should send mail to its owner to check it.

Comment: @Ali_T yes you can write that logic where i have used `echo ..`

Comment: just one thing I want to pass "tr . . . " result to variable as "pid" to get the elapsed time,but while is pipelined with it...any idea ?

Comment: @Ali_T if you store in a variable called `pid`, you will have to use the while loop on that variable `pid` not in the above format

Comment: It was ok I used $line as my variable,and worked just fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tr` to squeeze the spaces and then use `cut` to take the second space delimited field:

```
tr -s ' ' <idle_log.txt | cut -d' ' -f2
```

Or `awk`:

```
awk '{ print $2 }' idle_log.txt
```

Or `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/^[^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+([^[:blank:]]+)(.*)/\1/' idle_log.txt
```

Or `grep`:

```
grep -Po '^[^\s]+\s+\K[^\s]+' idle_log.txt
```

---

To use/count them later use an array:

```
pids=( $(tr -s ' ' <idle_log.txt | cut -d' ' -f2) )

num_of_pids="${#pids[@]}"

$ printf '%s\n' "${pids[@]}" 
2609
2758
28811
32200
32252
```

---

**Example:**

```
$ tr -s ' ' <file.txt | cut -d' ' -f2 
2609
2758
28811
32200
32252

$ awk '{ print $2 }' file.txt        
2609
2758
28811
32200
32252

$ sed -r 's/^[^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+([^[:blank:]]+)(.*)/\1/' file.txt
2609
2758
28811
32200
32252

$ grep -Po '^[^\s]+\s+\K[^\s]+' file.txt
2609
2758
28811
32200
32252
```

Comment: hmmm,nice trick but I still need to get values like one at each time .

Comment: thank you for your time I just used the first answer that was more close to my case.

Answer (score 1):

grep with Perl regex:

```
grep -oP '^[\S]+\s+\K[\S]+' file
2609
2758
28811
32200
32252
```

Or,

```
grep -o '^\([^[:blank:]]*[[:blank:]]*\)\{2\}' file |grep -o '[0-9]\+'
2609
2758
28811
32200
32252
```

Answer (score 0):

`cut` uses exactly the delimiter you pass it. That means with delimiter `' '`, the first line is:

```
postgres, <empty>, 2609
```

And the last one is:

```
postgres, 32252
```

You can simplify this by running just `awk '{print $2}' idle_log.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for the simplest solution:

```
pid=$(awk '{print $2}' idle_log.txt)
echo $pid
```

The regex stuff for sed and grep are much less readable in a script while cut and tr may sometimes have unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

As has already been pointed out, the reason, you were not getting, the results is that you were not extracting the second column.

Instead, you were using the command `cut -d" " -f2` so you were getting the second tablespaced split of each line . You may see that there is an additional tablespace for the two first lines so you should use `cut -d" " -f3` but as discussed, this is not the right way to get the second column. Use `awk '{print $2}'` instead.