# How to create a script to add, commit and push file by file a set of new or changed files?

Tags: git, shell

I want to create a `shell` script that `add`, `commit` and `push` new or changed files to a repository. Currently, my script is doing this by iterating file by file, which takes too much time. My requirement is to still doing this file by file, but this time I just want to iterate over the new or changed files.

My `shell` script is as follows:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

CUR_DIR=$(pwd)
PROJECT_DIR="${CUR_DIR}"

for fileToCommit in $(find ${PROJECT_DIR}/* -type f);
do
  test -f "$fileToCommit" || continue
  printf "%s\n" "${fileToCommit}"
  git add "${fileToCommit}"
  git commit -a -m "[ADD] New ${fileToCommit##*/} File"
  git push
done
```

**How can I do it in an effortless way?**

Comment: Why file by file? Anyway, even with that odd requirement of one file per commit, you could at least get the push line out of the loop. Would still be long, but much faster.

Comment: Because of GitHub limitations. As my project is working with small size, yet a huge number of files per repository, I require a single file `commit`. Hence, I need to do it file by file.

Comment: Not sure, if you scale it for several files, it can break the pipe. Although you are right, it could be dangerous. Indeed, get the `push` outside the loop line will make things much faster. However, GitHub has limitations for the size of the `push` instruction.

Comment: I'll just suggest here that if you're working hard to defeat some GitHub restriction using some code to automate a way to sidestep that restriction, you're *probably* setting yourself up for future pain too, when GitHub close that particular workaround loophole. It makes more sense to contact GitHub support and find out why they have some particular restriction and what you can do to work *with them* to get past it, rather than sneaking around it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `git status` [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status):

```txt
--porcelain[=<version>]
    Give the output in an easy-to-parse format for scripts.
    This is similar to the short output,
    but will remain stable across Git versions and regardless of user configuration.
```

This is the intended way to gather all changed/untracked/deleted files for scripts. It will give you an easy to parse output, still allowing you to handle all files individually if desired.

Furthermore, I think it would be wise to look into what `porcelain` means in git terminology. It will help you write reliable scripts across different git versions.

[What does the term "porcelain" mean in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6976473/10951000)

A small example of how you can use this:

```sh
filesToPush=$(git status --porcelain | awk '{print $2}')

for file in $filesToPush; do
    # Your actions.
done
```

This example considers that you want to do the same actions for all files returned by `git status`. If you want different behavior for different file statuses (changed, deletion, untracked), you will need to extract column 1 as well and change behavior dependent on this.

[How to get the second column from command output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16136943/10951000)

Comment: How should I change my script to have that behavior?

Comment: @FranciscoMariaCalisto I added a minimal explanation. I would look more into commands like `awk` and `sed` if you want more complex behavior.

Comment: It works fine. Thank you for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

#### Try this!

```html
for file in $(git ls-files --others)
do
   git add $file
   git commit -m "adding $file ✅"
   git push -u origin main
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a oneliner:

```bash
for f in $(git status --porcelain | sed "s/^...//");do git add $f; git commit -sam "commit message - $f";done
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).