# Why does PHP return 0 even though the disk is full

Tags: php, exit-code

I'm redirecting the stdout of php process(cli mode) to a file.

**Why exit code is 0 when disk is full.**

I can reappear this problem in php 7.1/5.6/5.4 and both in macos and centos.

```sh
leojins-MacBook-Pro-2:Downloads leojin$ php test.php > /Volumes/disk_test/test.log
leojins-MacBook-Pro-2:Downloads leojin$ echo $?
0
leojins-MacBook-Pro-2:Downloads leojin$ df -h
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused               ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s1   233Gi   27Gi  205Gi    12%  580000 9223372036854195807    0%   /
devfs          189Ki  189Ki    0Bi   100%     654                   0  100%   /dev
/dev/disk1s4   233Gi  1.0Gi  205Gi     1%       1 9223372036854775806    0%   /private/var/vm
map -hosts       0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0                   0  100%   /net
map auto_home    0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0                   0  100%   /home
/dev/disk2s1    95Mi   93Mi  1.5Mi    99%      96 9223372036854775711    0%   /Volumes/disk_test
```

Following is the content of `test.php`:

```php
<?php
$i = 0;
while (true) {
    echo "php:" . $i . "\n";
    $i++;
}
```

When i use python, it exit with 1 as expected.

```sh
leojins-MacBook-Pro-2:Downloads leojin$ python test.py > /Volumes/disk_test/test.log
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    print 'python:' + str(i)
IOError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
leojins-MacBook-Pro-2:Downloads leojin$ echo $?
1
```

Following is the content of `test.py`:

```py
i = 0 
while True:
    print 'python:' + str(i)
    i = i + 1
```

I also tried `php -d implicit_flush=0` and `python -u`, there is no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP code does no writing to disk, nor are you [setting an exit status](https://www.php.net/exit) anywhere in your code. So, it has no reason to exit abnormally. If you want to check if a disk is full, I suggest you do that [in your shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8110530/1255289), or [in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.disk-free-space.php).

I'm not that familiar with it but I'd guess your Python interpreter is probably throwing this error because the code is [compiled to bytecode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6889747/1255289) before being executed. If there's no space then it would be unable to perform this intermediate step.

Comment: To confirm that, just disable generstion of  `*.pyc` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154443/how-to-avoid-pyc-files